# Write IF statement using FormulaR1C1 in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have the following formula 
        `=IF((GLOBAL_DATE-30)<G2,"1 Month",IF((GLOBAL_DATE-60)<G2,"2 Month",IF((GLOBAL_DATE-90)<G2,"3 Month","Older Than 3 Months")))`
and I would like to write this into specific cells using the FormualR1C1 in VBA.
(the GLOBAL_DATE is a named cell on another sheet)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I get using the Macro Recorder:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF((GLOBAL_DATE-30)<R[1]C[6],""1 Month"",IF((GLOBAL_DATE-60)<R[1]C[6],""2 Month"",IF((GLOBAL_DATE-90)<R[1]C[6],""3 Month"",""Older Than 3 Months"")))"
```

That is using relative cell addresses (R[1]C[6] is the cell one row below and 6 columns to the rigth from the ActiveCell. Alternatively, you can use absolute adresses by replacing R[1]C[6] by R2C7 (for row 2, column 7 = G2).

Answer (score 1):

Select the cell that has that formula.  In the VBE, go to the Immediate Window and type

```
?Activecell.FormulaR1C1
```

and press enter.  That will give you the R1C1 translation of your formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use VBA to translate those formulae that you entered in a sheet into a sytax that's suitable for VBA.  I once wrote [a sub](http://idevlop.blogspot.com/2009/09/generer-du-vba-avec-excel-vba.html) for that purpose.